# Packaging and Transforming Source Code Using NuGet

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I'm currently working on a little pet project that takes a code file and deploys it using NuGet. I can currently replace the namespaces in the project using the $rootnamespace$ token and the .pp extension, but I'm curious if there is a better way.

My chief complaint is that I have to take code which builds correctly and transform it temporarily into something that no longer does so.

Is there a way for me to perform these transformations without having to alter my source code directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I created a very simple NuGet Preprocessor that looks at my solution and creates a shadow copy that has been tokenized and transformed to adhere to the NuGet standard. Works like a charm and now I can very easily deploy source files directly.

Comment: That's a very good point! And I agree that's it's a pain that when you change code in a .pp file that you can't tell if it will fail to compile. Any chance you could share the code you used to accomplish your solution?

Comment: Sure, I'll put it out on github later this week.